# How to make edit text scrollable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing the UI for one activity.In that activity I have added one scroll view .In that scroll view I have added one linear layout & in that linear layout I have added one edit text.Now I want to make that edit text as scrollable so how it will be possible?

Comment: You need to have enough controls in layout for the scroll bar to become active.   Not sure with one edit text you can get it to scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code..

```
  // For horizontal scroll  
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"  

  //For vertical scroll
 android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Comment: try this *android:scrollbars = "vertical"* in your Edittext tag in xml

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a scrollview inside of a scrollview

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

From **XML** you can try with..

```
<EditText
    android:id ="@+id/editInput"
    android:layout_width ="0dip" 
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight ="1" 
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines ="4" 
    android:maxLength ="2000"   />
```

Else, follow these..

- [android edittext is not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071655/android-edittext-is-not-scrolling)
- [Android EditText Vertical Scrolling Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123973/android-edittext-vertical-scrolling-problem/6124165#6124165)
- [How to make an EditText scrollable inside a scrollable LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682921/how-to-make-an-edittext-scrollable-inside-a-scrollable-linearlayout)